# Why does Laravel introduce a phamtom column in phpmyadmin database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I am creating an Photo album project. Where one can upload an image then by clicking on the image to a new page the user is able to upload many photos that will be contained in that album.

This is the error I am am getting:

```
`SQLSTATE[42S22]:Column not found: 1054 Unknown column'fashphotos.fash_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select*from`fashphotos' where `fashphotos`.`fash_id` in (3))'
```

The issue here is that there is no column in the database or in my code called "fash_id". However, the image is uploaded to the database.

Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Fash extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = array('name','cover_image');

     public function photos(){
         return $this->hasMany('App\Fashphoto');
     }
 }
```

Controller

```
use App\Fash;

class FashsController extends Controller
{
  public function index(){
  $albums = Fash::with('Photos')->get();
    return view('albums/fash.index')->with('albums', $albums);
 }


  
        public function create(){
        return view('albums/fash.create');
  }


  public function store(Request $request){
  $this->validate($request, [
  'name' => 'required',
  'cover_image' => 'required|dimensions:max_width=140,max_height=210'
  ]);

  $filenamewithExt = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();
$filename = pathinfo($filenamewithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extension =     $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
$filetostore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

$path = $request->file('cover_image')->storeAs('public/album_covers', $filetostore);

    //Create album
        $album = new Fash;
        $album->name = $request->input('name');
        $album->cover_image = $filetostore;

        $album->save();

        return redirect('/albums/fash')->with('success','Album Created');
   }
```

Migration

```
 public function up()
 {
    Schema::create('fashphotos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('fashalbum_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('photo');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
 }
```

This is what I have done so far to fix my problem
I performed a project search in an attempt to find the word. I have also performed these commands

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear 
composer dump-autoload
```

Your help will be very much appreciated

Comment: is there some model with a relationship method named `fash`?

Comment: do you have fashphoto factory or seeds or other migrations who alters and add new columns? Can you check if you create foreign keys on Photo migrations that is poiting to the fash_id?

Comment: lagbox yes there is. JMoura there is no factory or seeds

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find it from the code you provided but I have an idea as to what your issue could be caused by. Laravel is quite smart, when you create relationships between models if you don't define what column will be used as foreign id it will automagically expect it to be called `classname_id`. This is Laravel convention.

If this does not help you I'd need more information to help you. I can see you are calling model `Fash` in your controller but the model is actually called `Fashion` this could be clarified. Also, it would be useful to know when and where that error is thrown.

Comment: Thanks Samuel Reque Gallego, I don't know where the Fashion comes from it is Fash. The error occurs  when I try to upload an image, I have a create.blade.php page. When I press the Submit button I get the error